# Does the computer still process GUI even if the monitor is not connected?

Tags: linux, display, gui, processing

I know that GUI processing puts a load on the RAM and processor. I want to reduce that load on the pc. It is an old pc and was thinking of running it as a server using Linux.

Does the absence of monitor reduces that load?

Comment: `Does the computer still process GUI even if the monitor is not connected?` Yes. `Does the absence of monitor reduces that load?` Yes, generically sure.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use a text interface as is common in most server installs.

There are multiple factors to this.

If the PC is NOT RUNNING a GUI (ie it's in text mode - common for a server install) then it will be using very, very little power towards the graphics.

If the PC is running a GUI it depends on the amount of activity. When something is happening on the screen (regardless of whether the monitor is plugged in), the computer needs to calculate the changes. These calculations are what use processor power.  If you use a lightweight GUI like lxde it's going to use a lot less then a graphically advanced GUI which handles things like transparency and Window effects. ( normally using compiz or equivalent for rendering).

There is, of-course, a signal flowing when the monitor is on- this can use power, but not a significant amount.

A monitor, of course consumes power. When it's off, it's not using power.

Answer (score 0):

No, not having a monitor does not reduce the load.  All the video is still being processed by the graphics card, regardless of whether of not a monitor is attached.  This means the CPU, RAM, GPU, VRAM is still being used.  You *can* reduce the load by using a not GUI install, or by lowering the graphics settings, but this might not affect performance.  If the default booted interface isnt processing anything, then you are saving on performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question was "Does the absence of monitor reduces that load?" so I'll try answering that more directly.

In the case of Windows and Linux and most OSs applications limit their redrawing when they are out of focus and/or out of view in the window manager. Some games will limit their frame rate when out of focus which also would reduce resource load.

As seen in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qvb9m91y/1/
Firefox will stop rendering when its out of focus or tabs are switched.

The actual quality of having the monitor unplugged doesn't necessarily make an application think its out of focus however. Testing on a dual monitor setup Firefox and Linux are well aware that its out of view when the monitor is unplugged. So to answer your question yes, it will most of the time.